# Session connection full information

Tags: sql-server

session Connection full information

I am currently running the query and capturing session connection information which collects login, NT User, Host, Application/Program, Server and database information but i am also looking more granular detail which also tell me if it's executing SSIS package then which SSIS package, if it's tableau reports as application/program then which Database objects it's pulling the reports or other application/batch job doing any DML activities.

If i can't get all the above details but as a example if it's running SSIS package then which SSIS package running i can get it?

I am running currently couple different query as a daily sql job and storing the data into table.

```
SELECT @@ServerName AS SERVER
```

,NAME
 ,login_time
 ,last_batch
 ,getdate() AS DATE
 ,STATUS
 ,hostname
 ,program_name
 ,nt_username
 ,loginame
FROM sys.databases d
LEFT JOIN sys.sysprocesses sp ON d.database_id = sp.dbid
WHERE database_id NOT BETWEEN 0 AND 4
 AND loginame IS NOT NULL

Any other way i can more details as we will be doing migration wanted to make sure?

Ex. If SSIS loading data into DB, we need to find that SSIS package

Currently I am able to identify all connections established to the instance and where they are coming from, but 
we need to know which of those connections are feeding data and which are consuming data.

Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer is No.

When an application connects, it can have an ApplicationName passed in the connection details. You can retrieve it easily enough from the program_name column when you query sys.dm_exec_sessions. But it has to be configured in the connection string (in the SSIS data source) for you to be able to retrieve it.

Adding an ApplicationName to your connection strings is a good habit, not just for this, but for many tuning/monitoring reasons.

Comment: Thanks Greg. I am also using dbo.dm_exec_sessions_history. I am getting following Program Name: Program_Name
Tableau
SAP BusinessObjects
SQLAgent - TSQL Job
Batch Job Schedular
Microsoft JDBC Driver for SQL Server
SAP BusinessObjects Enterprise
SBOP Crystal Reports
.Net SqlClient Data Provider

Answer (score 0):

You can query the SSISDB catalog system view, [catalog.executions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/system-views/catalog-executions-ssisdb-database?view=sql-server-ver15), to find SSIS package executions on the server:

```
SELECT * FROM ssisdb.catalog.executions
```

Comment: Thank you Mitch. We are on older version so we don't have SSISDB yet but we are in planning to upgrade it.